# AngularJS Resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS. 
My services:

```
services.factory('Model', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('model/:id', {}, {});
}
]);

services.factory('Department', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('department/:id', {}, {});
}
]);

services.factory('Price', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('price/:id', {}, {});
}
]);
```

My controller:

```
controllers.controller('SafeNewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Safe', 'Model', 'Department', 'Price',
function ($scope, $location, Safe, Model, Department, Price) {
    $scope.models = Model.query();
    $scope.departments =Department.query();
    $scope.prices = Price.query();

    // It doesn't work. console.log($scope.models[0] 'and other') = undefined.
    $scope.safe = {model: $scope.models[0], department: $scope.departments[0], price: $scope.prices[0]};

    $scope.save = function () {
        var safe = new Safe($scope.safe);
        safe.$save(function () {
            $location.path('list/f');
        })
    }
}
]);
```

I got array of Resources after each query().
How can I get normal JSON as array and first objects of arrays to set to the $scope.safe?

Comment: The calls are async so you can't immediately access the results since they haven't been obtained you need to use the response handlers to handle this, unfortunately because of how $resource works this isn't entirely trivial... using $http in this case is actually a bit easier because you get a promise back and could use $q.all() to take care of all the results I'll try to write something up though.

Comment: Ah just double checked the docs it appears you can get the original promise so will be guessing below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controllers.controller('SafeNewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Safe', 'Model', 'Department', 'Price', '$q',
function ($scope, $location, Safe, Model, Department, Price, $q) {
    $scope.models = Model.query();
    $scope.departments =Department.query();
    $scope.prices = Price.query();

    $q.all([$scope.models.$promise, $scope.departments.$promise, $scope.prices.$promise]).then(function(){
        $scope.safe = {model: $scope.models[0], department: $scope.departments[0], price: $scope.prices[0]};
        console.log($scope.models[0]);
    })



    $scope.save = function () {
        var safe = new Safe($scope.safe);
        safe.$save(function () {
            $location.path('list/f');
        })
    }
}
]);
```